# Create PySpark dataframe from dictionary with list as values

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dictionary like this:

```
mydict = {
    'a': ["audi", "honda"],
    'b': ["toyota", "chevy"],
    'c': ["bmw", "ford"]
}
```

I want to convert this dictionary into a PySpark dataframe. I want a dataframe like this:

```
   topic    id    brand
    a       s1    audi
    a       s2    honda
    b       s3    toyota
    b       s4    chevy
    c       s5    bmw
    c       s6    ford
```

Where the col_names = `['topic', 'id', 'brand']` and all three are string type.

Any help is appreciated. It is easy to convert a dictionary to spark-dataframe if the length of the keys are the same as the values. But, here, I want to split the values...and tag the same key...and then convert to dataframe.

UPDATE: I have a crude solution (without `id`s):

```
master_topic_list = []
master_id_list = []
master_brand_list = []

for k, v in topic_related_dict.items():
    n = len(v)
    topic_list = [k] * n
    #id_list = ['s'+str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]

    master_topic_list.extend(topic_list)
    #master_id_list.extend(id_list)
    master_brand_list.extend(v)


col_names = ['topic', 'brand']
df = spark.createDataFrame(zip(list(master_topic_list), list(master_brand_list)), col_names)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

Import necessary packages:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, explode, row_number, concat
```

1. Create DataFrame from dictionary

```
mydict = {
    'a': ["audi", "honda"],
    'b': ["toyota", "chevy"],
    'c': ["bmw", "ford"]
}

df = spark.createDataFrame(mydict.items(), "topic STRING, brand ARRAY<STRING>")
```

2. Explode each value

```
df = df.withColumn("brand", explode("brand"))
```

3. Create Unique Identifier

```
id_spec = Window.orderBy(col("topic"))

df = df.withColumn("id", concat(lit("s"), row_number().over(id_spec)))

df.show()
```

**Output:**

```
+-----+------+---+
|topic| brand| id|
+-----+------+---+
|    a|  audi| s1|
|    a| honda| s2|
|    b|toyota| s3|
|    b| chevy| s4|
|    c|   bmw| s5|
|    c|  ford| s6|
+-----+------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us define a function to yield records for each unique combination of topic and brand

```
def flatten(d):
    ix = 1
    for k, v in d.items():
        for u in v:
            yield (k, f's{ix}', u)
            ix += 1


cols = ['topic', 'id', 'brand']
df = spark.createDataFrame(list(flatten(mydict)), cols)
```

---

```
df.show()
+-----+---+------+
|topic| id| brand|
+-----+---+------+
|    a| s1|  audi|
|    a| s2| honda|
|    b| s3|toyota|
|    b| s4| chevy|
|    c| s5|   bmw|
|    c| s6|  ford|
+-----+---+------+
```